# combining 2 time series

Tags: mysql, time-series

I am working with price data for futures contracts. I have data for Dec. 2010 and Mar. 2011, that I have loaded into the db.
I want to generate a flat file with the time series that includes both contracts. So, let's say Dec. 2010 expires on Dec. 31, 2010. On that day I will switch to the prices from the Mar. '11 contract. Before that, I do not want to capture the Mar. 11 contract.
I know how to do the first step of the process, i.e. get the data for the Dec. 2010 contract, but I am trying to figure out if I should run a separate query and append to the data file, or is there a way I can modify my SQL to handle the above.
This is the code I have written in my perl file.

```
my $sql=SELECT c_name, t_date, t_price,t_volume FROM $tblname where c_name='FZ10';
```

If I write a second query, that will be:

```
my $sql=SELECT c_name, t_date, t_price,t_volume FROM $tblname where c_name='FH11';

my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql) or die $dbh->errstr;
$sth->execute or die $sth->errstr;
open(FOUT, "> prices.dat");
```

Can you please let me know what is the best way to combine these 2 time series (given the date constraints) into a flat file.
thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is the UNION operator. Try that query:

```
SELECT c_name, t_date, t_price,t_volume FROM $tblname where c_name='FZ10'
UNION
SELECT c_name, t_date, t_price,t_volume FROM $tblname where c_name='FH11'
```

Comment: thanks @Traroth, that works. I guess since I want FH11 to start after Dec.31,2010, I can just include a WHERE clause to limit the dates.

Comment: Yes, you can do that. Also, for the more general case, you should look at the difference between UNION DISTINCT, which is the default behavior and UNION ALL, which includes the doublets between the two selects (in you case, there can't be any doublet, since c_name is in the where clause and in the select clause)